# wso2 convert xml to json with array

Tags: json, xml, xslt, wso2

I am trying to convert xml to json using an xslt. When I have single node, the JSON output does not contain an array, but when it has multiple nodes it will show up as an array

If I have single Report Entry then JSON output is as follows (missing the array):

XML:

```
<Report_Data>
    <Report_Entry>
        <ID>0025440</ID>
    </Report_Entry>
</Report_Data>
```

Results:

```
{
    "Report_Data": {
        "Report_Entry": 
            {  "ID": "0025440" }
    }
}
```

---

When I have multiple entry in XML then the output is as follows (array exists):

XML:

```
<Report_Data>
    <Report_Entry>
        <ID>0025440</ID>
    </Report_Entry>
    <Report_Entry>
        <ID>00254401</ID>
    </Report_Entry>
</Report_Data>
```

Results:

```
{
    "Report_Data": {
        "Report_Entry": [
            { "ID": "0025440" },
            { "ID": "0025441" }
        ]
    }
}
```

---

This is a sample Input XML File Trying to Add Arrays in WSo2. This fails to add arays in JSON output.

> a345ea1b59d
>                           
>                           
>                               c867b9511fa201
>
> > CCH2
> >                                 
> >                             
> >                             
> >                                 c867b9511fa201
> >                                 
> >                                 
> >                             
> >                           
> >                                 c867b9511fa201
> >                                 
> >                                 
> >                             
> >                             5005854
>
> ```
>                     <xyz:AStatus xyz:Descriptor="Pending">
>                         <xyz:ID xyz:type="ID">5e3ae98c7e4b4af9836cd</xyz:ID>
>                         <xyz:ID xyz:type="DID">PENDING</xyz:ID>
>                     </xyz:AStatus>
>
>                     <xyz:Net>0</xyz:Net>
>                     <xyz:AMoment>2019-10-10</xyz:AMoment>
>                 </xyz:Report_Entry>
>             </xyz:Report_Data>
>         </env:Body>
>     </env:Envelope>
> </xyz:Body> </xyz:Envelope>
> ```

This is formatted properly with out any issues since it has multiple Report Entrys:

> a345ea1b59d
>                           
>                           
>                               c867b9511fa201
>
> > CCH2
> >                                 
> >                             
> >                             
> >                                 c867b9511fa201
> >                                 
> >                                 
> >                             
> >                           
> >                                 c867b9511fa201
> >                                 
> >                                 
> >                             
> >                             5005854
>
> ```
>                     <xyz:AStatus xyz:Descriptor="Pending">
>                         <xyz:ID xyz:type="ID">5e3ae98c7e4b4af9836cd</xyz:ID>
>                         <xyz:ID xyz:type="DID">PENDING</xyz:ID>
>                     </xyz:AStatus>
>
>                     <xyz:Net>0</xyz:Net>
>                     <xyz:AMoment>2019-10-10</xyz:AMoment>
>                 </xyz:Report_Entry>
>                <xyz:Report_Entry>
>                     <xyz:BusinessAsset xyz:Descriptor="12">
>                         <xyz:ID xyz:type="ID">a345ea1b59d</xyz:ID>
>                     </xyz:BusinessAsset>
>                     <xyz:CH xyz:Descriptor="UCCH2">
>                         <xyz:ID xyz:type="ID">c867b9511fa201</xyz:ID>
>                         <xyz:ID xyz:type="OID"
>                             >CCH2</xyz:ID>
>                         <xyz:ID xyz:type="CID"
>                             >CCH2</xyz:ID>
>                     </xyz:CH>
>                     <xyz:CH xyz:Descriptor="UCCH3">
>                         <xyz:ID xyz:type="ID">c867b9511fa201</xyz:ID>
>                         <xyz:ID xyz:type="OID"
>                             >CCH3</xyz:ID>
>                         <xyz:ID xyz:type="CID"
>                             >CCH3</xyz:ID>
>                     </xyz:CH>
>                   <xyz:CH xyz:Descriptor="UCCH4">
>                         <xyz:ID xyz:type="ID">c867b9511fa201</xyz:ID>
>                         <xyz:ID xyz:type="OID"
>                             >CCH4</xyz:ID>
>                         <xyz:ID xyz:type="CID"
>                             >CCH4</xyz:ID>
>                     </xyz:CH>
>                     <xyz:AID>5005854</xyz:AID>
>
>                     <xyz:AStatus xyz:Descriptor="Pending">
>                         <xyz:ID xyz:type="ID">5e3ae98c7e4b4af9836cd</xyz:ID>
>                         <xyz:ID xyz:type="DID">PENDING</xyz:ID>
>                     </xyz:AStatus>
>
>                     <xyz:Net>0</xyz:Net>
>                     <xyz:AMoment>2019-10-10</xyz:AMoment>
>                 </xyz:Report_Entry>
>             </xyz:Report_Data>
>         </env:Body>
>     </env:Envelope>
> </xyz:Body> </xyz:Envelope>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try this:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="Report_Data">
        <xsl:text>{</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>&#x2003;"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/><xsl:text>":</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="Report_Entry">
            <xsl:text>{</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>&#x2003;&#x2003;"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/><xsl:text>":</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="ID">
                <xsl:if test="following-sibling::* and position()=1">[&#x0A;</xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="not(following-sibling::*) and position()=1"><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
                <xsl:text>&#x2003;&#x2003;&#x2003;{</xsl:text><xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="local-name()"/><xsl:text>": </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;',.,'&quot;')"/><xsl:text>}</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::* and position()=last()">&#x2003;&#x2003;]&#x0A;</xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:text>&#x2003;}</xsl:text><xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>}</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I just provided a sample data. But My xml is more complex and have nested node and arrays. I want to create a generic xslt, rather than hard coding the square brackets for one scenario

Comment: @SPB if you have other nested nodes then you S/B use nested xsl:for-each.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to present 'Report_Entry' as a JSON array, regardless of it has one or many elements, this needs to be done inside the XSLT file and need to include below XML processing instruction.

```
<xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-multiple">Report_Entry</xsl:processing-instruction>
```

Comment: I just gave a sample data. But there are more nested arrays inside my report entry. wso2 erroring when I am adding the above statement :Unable to perform XSLT transformation using : Value {name ='null', keyValue ='gov:trunk/xslt/transform.xsl'